# SQL Query With Multiple Fields Rolled Into One Record

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have the following query:

```
SELECT     KEY,
           BILL,
           CODE      
FROM       TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.KEY = TABLE2.KEY
ORDER      TABLE1.KEY;
```

And this outputs the following Table

```
KEY  |  BILL |  CODE
1234 |  AAA  |  ABC
1234 |  AAA  |  BCD
1234 |  AAA  |  DEF
```

Is there a way to query to return the record as:
`1234 AAA ABC AAA BCD AAA DEF`?
I basically want to roll up every output for each record that has the same key. This is in Oracle.

Comment: post data for table1 and table2

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) :

```
SELECT KEY,
       LISTAGG(BILL||' '||CODE, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BILL||' '||CODE)     
   FROM TABLE1
   INNER JOIN TABLE2
   ON TABLE1.KEY = TABLE2.KEY
   ORDER TABLE1.KEY
GROUP BY KEY
```

Comment: I tried this and I end up with an oversized string concatenation. Tried converting each field to_clob and it still failed.

Comment: Yes, you can't use this approach for rows larger than 4000 characters. On the other hand if you have such large rows, maybe you are not supposed to use concatenation...